Why is the http.route Tag Missing in Jaeger Traces with OpenTelemetry on .NET 5 but Present on .NET 6?
I am using OpenTelemetry Version=1.8.1 and OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger Version=1.5.1 with .NET 5. When writing traces to Jaeger, the http.route tag is missing. I have another API based on .NET 6, where I use the same versions of OpenTelemetry libraries and the same setup, and in that case, the http.route tag appears as expected. Is this an issue with .NET 5, or could it be an incompatibility problem causing the missing tag?

It may be the jaeger exporter.  See https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/1160
